# Excel Task Pane add-in to show content from external source

Tags: excel, office-addins, customtaskpane

I am trying to build an Excel/Word task pane add-in that should show content from our site. The content/data is passed in XML format.

What I have tried to do is the following:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        app.initialize();

        $.support.cors = true;

        var data = '';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http://addons.mysite.com/excel-taskpane-data.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: onQuerySuccess,
            error: onQueryError
        });

        function onQuerySuccess(res, statusText) {
            console.log('success!!' + res.statusText);
        }
        function onQueryError(res, statusText){
            console.log('failed!!' + res.statusText);
        }

  });

};
```

As you can understand from the code above I was just checking if connection could be made to the external source, but I am getting "Access Denied" in the console.

I am not really sure how should I request data from an external source and whether it is possible at all?

Please help

Comment: Are you sure all this is about office addins and not about Apps for office?

Comment: @AlexButenko Apps for Office have been renamed as Office add-ins. Now this terminology refers to both technologies, which is extremely error prone

Comment: @BenoitPatra oh, thanks, I was absolutely sure that office-addins tag is about .net addins. Maybe we need to edit the tag descriptions then.

Comment: @AlexButenko for outlook add-ins a tag outlook-web-addins has been created but not for all office-addins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned 'external' so I bet *http://addons.mysite.com/* is not the domain that serves your web add-in.
To make it work you have to check several things.

1. Serving with Https. As written by Michael make sure you use https. [Mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/MixedContent) (mixing of http and https) is blocked by most server and Office web add-ins can only be served with https.
2. Make sur your PHP web api supports CORS.
   I am no PHP expert so here is a [small link](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html)
3. Try to specify https://addons.mysite.com as AppDomain
   The sandboxed iFrame allow only request and navigation on the same domain (the one that you use to serve you web-addin). But you can specify some exceptions [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161044.aspx#bk_Preventing_Navigation). It works with navigation and I am not sure it works with XHR...
4. If step 3 did not work try to use JSON/P techniques as described here
   [JSON/P with Office add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123589.aspx)

Comment: I have followed all steps, but still no results in my Excel Add-on. I have actually changed the script slightly and all works just fine in the browser, but when I use the same js in my add-on, nothing happens.

Comment: found a problem, for some reason application cannot use the jquery in the Scripts folder so I have to add it to App folder and now wverything works like magic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make Ajax HTTP requests from Office web add-ins such as your Excel/Word task pane. They work exactly the same as they would on a normal web page, except we have an additional requirement of using "https" rather than "http" to access the endpoint.

I can't identify the cause of your specific issue without information about the actual endpoint you're calling. Start by just trying your code on a normal web page and access it normally with a web browser. Once you have that working, then point an add-in to the page. That should fix your issue, but if you still have a problem where the exact same code is working in a normal browser and failing in an add-in, let us know.